# How to skip a section in config file using configparser

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code where parameters are taken from a config file.
My first parameter in the config is for setting the debug level.

```
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config.cfg')
    log_level = config.get('Logger','log_level' )
```

There are other sections in the config which gives the server IP and password to scan each sections.

Main Code:

```
for section in config.sections():
    components = dict() #start with empty dictionary for each section
    env.user = config.get(section, 'server.user_name')
    env.password = config.get(section, 'server.password')
    host = config.get(section, 'server.ip')
```

From my config

```
[Logger]
#Possible values for logging are INFO, DEBUG and ERROR
log_level = DEBUG

[server1]
server.user_name = root
server.password = password
server.ip = 172.19.41.21
[server2]
server.user_name = root
server.password = password
server.ip = 172.19.41.21
```

Now my code says to check each section to retrieve the username and password. Since the first section doesn't contain these values, it's failing. How can i check each section for username and password and if its not there just go to the next section. I tried by checking for NONE and go to the next section. But that code is ugly and it's failing. Something like this:

```
if env.user=='':
        next
```

Can someone help me to proceed further?

Comment: Could you please post the piece of code you use to process the sections?

Comment: I'm assuming the server sections all start with `server` ? i.e `server1`, `sever2` etc etc?

Comment: @Cliyan...No. I just gave it as Server for example. The real server names will be displayed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to the beginning of your `for` loop:

```
if not config.has_option(section, 'server.user_name'):
    continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Since only the first section doesn't contain these values you can use the `iter` function.

```
sections = iter(config.sections())
next(sections)
for section in sections:
    # something(section)
```

Or as @tjohnson mentioned:

```
for section in config.sections()[1:]:
    # something(section)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do is to just catch the exception.

```
for section in config.sections():
    components = dict() #start with empty dictionary for each section
    try:
        env.user = config.get(section, 'server.user_name')
        env.password = config.get(section, 'server.password')
        host = config.get(section, 'server.ip')
    except ConfigParser.NoOptionError as e:
        continue # At least one required option is missing in the section, skip
```

The advantage is that if *any* option is missing, the section will be ignored.

However, if you need to be atomic (for example, if it is a problem to set
`env.user` if the section is finally ignored due to `server.ip` not present), you might
want something like this.

```
for section in config.sections():
    components = dict() #start with empty dictionary for each section
    try:
        tmp_user = config.get(section, 'server.user_name')
        tmp_password = config.get(section, 'server.password')
        tmp_host = config.get(section, 'server.ip')
    except ConfigParser.NoOptionError as e:
        continue # At least one required option is missing in the section, skip
    else:
        env.user = tmp_user
        env.password = tmp_password
        host = tmp_host
```

In that case, maybe it is easier to use `has_option` 3 times.